# Is this proof correct? Show that the residues are equal

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I solved the following question, but was unsure about a couple of details.

> Let $f$ be meromorphic in a neighborhood of $0$, $\phi$ analytic in a neighborhood of $0$, such that $\phi(0) = 0, \phi'(0) \neq 0$.

First of all, $\phi$ has a simple zero at $0$ and is nonconstant, so there exists a $c > 0$ such that $\phi, f$ are both analytic/meromorphic on an open set containing $D_c(0)$, and they have no zeroes or poles in $\overline{D_c(0)}$ except possibly at $0$. Then $$\int\limits_{|z|=r} \frac{\phi'}{\phi} = 2\pi i$$ by the argument principle, since $\phi$ has one simple zero in $D_c(0)$.  We can write $f(z)$ as a Laurent series $$\frac{a_{-n}}{z^n} + \cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{z} + a_0 + a_1z + \cdots$$ Now the image of $\phi$ under a very small neighborhood of $0$ is contained in $D_c(0)$, so on this small neighborhood the composition $f(\phi(z)) \phi'(z)$ remains a uniformly convergent power series in the variable $\phi(z)$: $$f(\phi(z)) = \frac{a_{-n}}{\phi(z)^n} + \cdots + \frac{a_{-1}}{\phi(z)} + a_0 + a_1\phi(z) + \cdots$$ What I'm having trouble justifying is the following step.  I multiply both sides of the above equation by $\phi'(z)$, and then integrate both sides and interchange the integral with the infinite sum.  For $n \geq 0$, it is clear that $\int\limits_{|z|=c} a_n \phi(z)^n \phi'(z)dz = 0$, since we're just integrating something analytic.  For $n < -1$, I also want to say that $\int\limits_{|z|=c} \frac{a_n}{\phi(z)^{-n}} \phi'(z)dz = 0$, but I'm not sure how to justify this, since the function I'm integrating should have a pole of order $n$ at $0$.  If all goes well, what I'll get is $$Res_0 [f \circ \phi] \phi' = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|z| = c} f(\phi(z)) \phi'(z) dz = \frac{a_{-1}}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|z|=c} \frac{\phi'(z)}{\phi(z)}dz = a_{-1} = Res_0 f$$

Comment: May I interrupt to ask what the question is?

Comment: @D_S Your question is not clear, what you want to prove?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I want to know why (or whether) it's true that $$\int\limits_{|z|=c} \frac{a_{-n}}{\phi(z)^{-n}} \phi'(z)dz = 0$$ for $n \geq 2$, since that would finish the proof for me.